# Menu Tokens module - CiviCRM profiles

Tags: civicrm, 7

I'm trying to use the [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) Module to create a menu item that links to the user overlay in Drupal so that users can find their CiviCRM profiles easily. So it should be going to something like:

```
/user/peradmin#overlay=user/%/edit
```

I'm having trouble working out how a token can be created - or found! Any ideas?

I've been following the instructions from [here](http://www.webomelette.com/drupal-7-menu-token) but I haven't worked it out.